# Reference formula 'Text' within another cell in Excel

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I would like to insert text from a cell into a formula.

For example, using the formula:

```
=LOOKUP(A1,'Sheet2'!B2:B10, 'Sheet2'!D2:D10)
```

I would like to change 'Sheet2' to some other reference (i.e. Sheet3) - this reference label is contained within another cell within the main spreadsheet.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: [Referencing A Sheet Indirectly](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/referencing_a_sheet_indirectly/)

Answer (score 1):

if you write the sheet name in C1, in sheet1 for example and the value your looking up is in A1 like the Formula above, write in B1 the following:
`=LOOKUP(A1,INDIRECT(C1&"!B2:B10"), INDIRECT(C1&"!D2:D10"))`
Indirect helps in reading the content of cell C1.